# For what real values of $k$ does $2x^3-3x^{21}-2x+1=k$ have exactly one real root?

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

This is meant to be a non-calculator university interview-style question.

From graphing software of the function on the LHS I can see the solution is

$k<0.23$, $0.43<k<1.57$, $k>1.77$

and due to the symmetry around $y=1$, only the turning points at $y=0.23$ and $y=0.43$ need to be found.

The problem I have is in actually finding these turning points "by hand". Differentiating leads to a polynomial of degree $20$ with no straightforward solution.

Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: very likely they intended   $2x^3-3x^2-2x+1=k$   rather than  $2x^3-3x^{21}-2x+1=k$

Comment: I second the vote for "typo".  The degree $21$ version has a couple of local critical points which would be very hard to get right by hand.  Also, it is highly unusual to write a polynomial in non-descending order.

Comment: @lulu   I also suggest that the linear term be deleted  as that makes everything integers; he mentions something about non-calculator interview.

Comment: @WillJagy  Good catch, though that's a harder typo to understand.  Anybody can hit  $21$ when meaning to hit $2$, but adding a whole term?

Comment: @lulu  I would guess this problem was given to the OP  by telephone (a friend)  rather than on paper.   Plenty of opportunities for error.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah  what is JWT ?

Comment: Thank you for the input. I suggested to my friend it was a typo but he was certain it was degree $21$. Must be a typo from whatever source he got it from. Apologies for time wasting - was hoping it was something interesting I hadn't spotted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $2x^3-3x^2-2x+1=k$ instead of  $2x^3-3x^{21}-2x+1=k$,

Let $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2-2x+1$

Then $f'(x)=6x^2-6x-2$

Thus, we can find the roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of $f'(x)=0$

Using the nature of the cubic's plot (not done using a graphing calculator), it is clear that only one solution exists if $k>f(\alpha)$ or $k<f(\beta)$, where $\alpha$ is the smaller root.

Answer (score 1):

If you recall the procedure for solving the cubic equation
$$2x^3-3x^2-2x+(1-k)=0$$ you firs eliminate the $x^2$ term to face a depressed cubic.

$$x=t- \frac{-3}{3\times 2}=t+ \frac 1{2}\quad \implies t^3-\frac{7 }{4}t-\frac{2k+1}{4} =0$$

Now, the dicriminant
$$\Delta=-4 \left(-\frac 74\right)^3-27\left(-\frac{2k+1}{4} \right)^2=-\frac 14 \left(27 k^2+27 k-79\right)$$ must be negative. So, any $k$ outside the roots of this quadratic will lead to a single real root.